# Could not be able to call methods onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpened

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

this is my custom method in which i am giving Drawer Layout and toolbar as an arguments but i am not able to call `drawerClose` and `drawerOpen` method

```
public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar)
{
    mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),mDrawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. Do you want to implement the `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()` listener methods? Or are you trying to use the `openDrawer()` and `closeDrawer()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

Because the methods are actually `closeDrawer` and `openDrawer`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html